# update value of a map of objects

Tags: json, dictionary, jq, edit

With jq, how can I transform the following:

```
{
  "root": {
    "branch1": {
      "leaf": 1
    },
    "branch2": {
      "leaf": 2
    },
    "branch3": {
      "leaf": 3
    }
  },
  "another-root": {
      "branch": 123
  },
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

to this:

```
{
  "root": {
    "branch1": {
      "leaf": "updated"
    },
    "branch2": {
      "leaf": "updated"
    },
    "branch3": {
      "leaf": "updated"
    }
  },
  "another-root": {
      "branch": 123
  },
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently `[]` can be used on object too. I had though it was only for lists.

The following was all I needed.

`.root[].leaf="updated"`

Comment: You still need to be careful in cases, where you don't have a `.leaf` path inside one of the objects. Your expression will incorrectly add it there and even worse, if you have an array containing different elements inside `.root`, there will be errors running your expression.

Answer (score -1):

First you need to parse the json and then modify the resulting object as required using `for ... in` statement (example below)

```
const flatJSON = '{"root":{"branch1":{"leaf":1},"branch2":{"leaf":2},"branch3":{"leaf":3}},"another-root":{"branch":123},"foo":"bar"}';

const parsedJSON = JSON.parse(flatJSON);
const root = parsedJSON.root;

for (let property in root) {
  root[property].leaf = "updated"; (or root[property]["leaf"] = "updated";)
}
```

If you want to use jquery you have to replace `for ... in` statement with `jQuery.each()` method that iterates over both objects and arrays.

Don't forget to convert it back to json with JSON.stringify() method (if required).

Hope that this helps.
All the best.

Comment: An earlier answer provided a solution in the [requested language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jq).